# When both players have same two pairs but the 5th card to make the best hand is a J and it’s on the board also in one of the players hands who wins?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

Board: K J A A 3
Player 1: K J
Player 2: K 2
Signs don’t matter since no one had a flush. From my understanding it’s a tie. Since the best hand is A A K K J and both players have the best hand. Doesn’t matter if player 1 had a J in their hand. But this is always an issue in my house hold. They believe because player 1 holds the J they win. And if there’s video proof of this please include since they also think they’ve seen it in professional poker games that the person with J wins.

Comment: If you want "proof", just tell your poker buddies to read Wikipedia, or this page.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Hold em poker hands have 5 cards only (including any combination of a players hole cards and the cards on the board), there is no 3-pair and no extra kickers for hands like straights and 2 pairs.